# The last known location is lost when we are not in getLastLocation() - Android

Tags: android

I am trying to create a method that will get the last known location and assign that value to a global variable that I will use later. I am following [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current) training.

In the end, this is the code that I've wrote:

```
public void getCurrentLocation() {
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
            if (location != null) {
                // Logic to handle location object
                mCurrentLocation = new Location(location);
                System.out.println("In method getCurrentLocation: Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() + " Longitude = " + location.getLongitude());
                System.out.println("In method getCurrentLocation for mCurrentLocation: Latitude = " + mCurrentLocation.getLatitude() + " Longitude = " + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
                } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Can't get the current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The `getCurrentLocation()` method I will call in the `onCreate()` method of `MainActivity` and I can see the prints from the method so my variable got a location, but if I try to use the `mCurrentLocation` in some other context (for example I want to go to the last known location using this variable) the variable will be `null`. I am not sure that I need `new Location(location)`, I added it because I thought that my variable will point to a `null` place in the memory after we exit the method, but it looks that it is not the case (I get the same outcome).

Comment: mCurrentLocation = location; you can direclty assign like this

Comment: Yes, but it will not solve my problem, after I exit the method the `mCurrentLocation` will still be `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few weeks later I came up with some sort of a explanation to what is happening and how I managed to get the result that I want. I only had to do the first 3 steps that @MustafaKhaled wrote in his answer, this will make the `mFusedLocationClient` global variable to have its `getLastLocation()` method called (I think this happens because I request location updates, see @MustafaKhaled post).

Now, what we do with the last location? The response is nothing, because we do not handle what will happen if we successfully retrieve the location.

That being said, we will need to add what will happen `onSuccess()` with the location. In my case, I had to retain the value of the `mCurrentLocation` so I still need the method from the initial post to be implemented:

```
    public void AddFusedLocationClientOnSuccessListener() {
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                if (location != null) {
                    // Logic to handle location object
                    mCurrentLocation = location;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Here I will be able to do some other things with the location if needed (for example if I want the application to animate to the current location), but later, if I when I use buttons or other graphical elements, I will be able to use the `mCurrentLocation` variable.

Now, I will be able to call the `mCurrentLocation` directly in the `onCreate()`? The answer is NO, because we will have to wait for `mFusedLocationClient` to successfully get the last known location, otherwise the`mCurrentLocation` will be null, that is the reason in the initial post it did not work, we were not calling the `getLastLocation()` method until we will get success.

I hope this answer will be helpful for other peoples that encounter this problem and they don't fully understand what happens in the onCreate().

Answer (score 2):

According to [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#last-known), **Last Known Location** could be **Null** in case of:

- Location is turned off in the device settings. As it clears the
  cache.
- The device never recorded its location. (New device)
- Google Play services on the device has restarted.

In this case, you should **requestLocationUpdates** and receive the new location on the **LocationCallback**.

By the following steps **your last known Location never null.**

---

Pre-requisite: 
[EasyPermission library](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions)

---

Step 1:
In manifest file add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

---

Step 2:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    //Create location callback when it's ready.
    createLocationCallback()

    //createing location request, how mant request would be requested.
    createLocationRequest()

    //Build check request location setting request
    buildLocationSettingsRequest()

    //FusedLocationApiClient which includes location 
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    //Location setting client
    mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this)

    //Check if you have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission
    if (!EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(
            this@MainActivity,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        requestPermissionsRequired()
    }
    else{
        //If you have the permission we should check location is opened or not
        checkLocationIsTurnedOn()
    }

}
```

---

Step 3:
Create required functions to be called in **onCreate()**

```
private fun requestPermissionsRequired() {
    EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
        this,
        getString(R.string.location_is_required_msg),
        LOCATION_REQUEST,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    )
}

private fun createLocationCallback() {
    //Here the location will be updated, when we could access the location we got result on this callback.
    mLocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult)
            mCurrentLocation = locationResult.lastLocation
        }
    }
}

private fun buildLocationSettingsRequest() {
    val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
    builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest!!)
    mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build()
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true)
}

private fun createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
    mLocationRequest!!.interval = 0
    mLocationRequest!!.fastestInterval = 0
    mLocationRequest!!.numUpdates = 1
    mLocationRequest!!.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
}

public fun checkLocationIsTurnedOn() { // Begin by checking if the device has the necessary location settings.
    mSettingsClient!!.checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
        .addOnSuccessListener(this) {
            Log.i(TAG, "All location settings are satisfied.")
            startLocationUpdates()
        }
        .addOnFailureListener(this) { e ->
            val statusCode = (e as ApiException).statusCode
            when (statusCode) {
                LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED -> {
                    try {
                        val rae = e as ResolvableApiException
                        rae.startResolutionForResult(this@MainActivity, LOCATION_IS_OPENED_CODE)
                    } catch (sie: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                    }
                }
                LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                    mRequestingLocationUpdates = false
                }
            }
        }
}

private fun startLocationUpdates() {
    mFusedLocationClient!!.requestLocationUpdates(
        mLocationRequest,
        mLocationCallback, null
    )
}
```

---

Step 4:

Handle callbacks in **onActivityResult()** after ensuring the location is opened or the user accepts to open it in.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when (requestCode) {
        LOCATION_IS_OPENED_CODE -> {
            if (resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Location result is OK")
            } else {
                activity?.finish()
            }
        }
}
```

---

Step 5:
Get last known location from FusedClientApi

```
override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = map
    mFusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener {
        if(it!=null){
            locateUserInMap(it)
        }
    }

}
   private fun locateUserInMap(location: Location) {
    showLocationSafetyInformation()
    if(mMap!=null){
        val currentLocation = LatLng(location.latitude,location.longitude )
        addMarker(currentLocation)
    }
}


private fun addMarker(currentLocation: LatLng) {
    val cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLocation)
    mMap?.clear()
    mMap?.addMarker(
        MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation)
            .title("Current Location")
    )
    mMap?.moveCamera(cameraUpdate)
    mMap?.animateCamera(cameraUpdate)
    mMap?.setMinZoomPreference(14.0f);
}
```

I hope this would help.

Happy Coding

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't understand how can I use my variable `mCurrentLocation` outside of any of this methods. I've also tried it and still get `null` errors

Comment: Maybe you are access mCurrentLocation before callback of getLastKnownLocation received. 
So, I suggest to make a callback that will guarantee your mCurrentLocation is initialized. 
Or, you can call your other code that depends on mCurrentLocation inside onSuccess Callback.